# How to properly disable spans used with input-group-addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have a span with the input-group-addon class. As we're all aware, using add-ons with other components is fairly common. The problem I have is disabling the span that has this class after I've disabled the input its tied to.

In my example, I use a calendar addon with a bootstrap datepicker component.

```
<div class="input-group date">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1" />

    <span class="input-group-addon" id="dp1Icon"><img src="<%=context%>/images/calendar-glyph.png"></span>

</div>
```

I define my Bootstrap datepicker as such:

```
var datePicker = $(".input-group.date").datepicker({myOptions});
```

Sometimes I disable my datepicker like this:

```
$("#dp1").prop("disabled", true);
```

But I can't disable the dp1Icon. I've researched quite a bit. First, there is no method "showing" in the bootstrap datepicker that'll allow me to trap and prevent default.

Second, "pointer-events:none" doesn't work on IE.

Third, using this won't work either:

```
$("#dp1Icon").click(function(e){// if it has a certain class, e.preventDefault()});
```

wont' work either.

I can easily remove the click handler like this:

```
$("#dp1Icon").off("click");
```

But then how do I re-assign it to open up the datepicker again? This doesn't work:

```
$("#dp1Icon").on("click",$(".input-group.date").datepicker("show");
```

What solutions am I left with? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Temporarily hide the span with css and replace with an identical element that has an greyed out icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proof of concept:

```js
$("#dp1Icon_blocked").off(); //remove all event 
function disable()
{
$("#dp1").prop("disabled", true);
$("#dp1Icon").addClass("hidden");
$("#dp1Icon_blocked").removeClass("hidden")

}

function enable()
{
$("#dp1").prop("disabled", false);
$("#dp1Icon").removeClass("hidden");
$("#dp1Icon_blocked").addClass("hidden")

}

//display purposes not part of the solution:
$($("button")[0]).click(disable);
$($("button")[1]).click(enable);
```

```css
.hidden{
 display: block;
}

.blocked {
   color: #c2c2c2 !important; /* The important overrides the settings from bootstrap */
   cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1" />

    <span class="input-group-addon" id="dp1Icon">Date</span>
    <span class="input-group-addon blocked hidden" id="dp1Icon_blocked">Date</span>
</div>

<button>Disable</button><button>Enable</button>
```

Comment: Not working. Not really sure what you're doing here. You're not hiding dp1Icon by adding the hidden class. The cursor not-allowed doesn't prevent the datepicker from being shown when they click on it.

Comment: Was trying to hide the original element `#dp1Icon` and replace it with an identical one. Thought it might work.

Comment: Right, and that totally makes sense but you're still not preventing a click on dp1Icon_blocked. All you're doing is setting cursor to not-allowed...and that doesn't work.

Comment: @fumeng Used jQuery's `off()` on the replaced element (preserving the original) as an edit here. That might work.

Comment: .off() definitely works to remove the click event. But how do I re-assign it back? I updated my original post to show you my attempt. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Then hide the second button and unhide the original button.

Comment: @fuming, take a look at the updated example. That should work.